# Stack Overflow icon instead of Stack Exchange icon in login page

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, design, login, icons

Not a serious bug, but when joining a new SE site, it says "using a login from Stack Exchange", whereas the Stack Overflow icon is used.

[image]

Comment: These kinds of minor inconsistencies set off the "you're getting phished!" alarm bells, especially on an account-related page (even though it's not a login page).